# ProgressBar Circle and corner Rounded (Android) Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

[enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBKDM.png)

I managed to make the progress bar circle, but I can't get corner rounded

Answer (score 0):

To get a circle progress bar you can search for "circle progress bars on github". This one is especially good. https://github.com/lopspower/CircularProgressBar/ Just make sure to put the implementation in your Build Grade for Modules and use the xml provided by the author.